# Hadoop:Why hdfs throw the SocketTimeoutException exception?

Tags: hadoop2

My `datanodes` sometimes throw an `SocketTimeoutException`.

> 2016-10-08 16:23:47,557 WARN
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: IOException in
>   offerService  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call From
>   hadoop-slave-xxx.com/slaveIp to hadoop-master-namenode-xxx.com:9000 f
>     ailed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
>   60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for rea    d.
>   ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/slaveIp:59710
>   remote=hadoop-namenode-xxx.com/namenodeIp:    9000]; For more details
>   see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout

I think,i can set `dfs.socket.timeout` to solve the problem,but i want to know,why throw the exception.

It is strange that the `datanodes` throw the exception at the same time.But the `namenode` is not doing a `full gc` at the exception time.

EDIT:

At that time hadoop balancer runs normally.

Comment: Is there any setting at OS level which limits open files etc ?

Comment: @ozw1z5rd,/proc/sys/fs/file-max = 13128612,Equivalent to no limit.

Comment: Datanode logs don't help too much to understand what is happening on namenode.  Before to post the namanode logs, double check how it is configured at OS and JVM level, I.E:  [namenode heap configuration](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.6/bk_installing_manually_book/content/ref-80953924-1cbf-4655-9953-1e744290a6c3.1.html)

Comment: @ozw1z5rd,There were just some addblock logs on the namenode log file,and no exception logs. I use `jstat` to confirm the namenode was not doing a `full gc`

Comment: @ozw1z5rd,At that time,hadoop balancer runs normally,so network should has no issues..

Comment: no ideas. (not yet)

Comment: @ozw1z5rd,Thank you.

Comment: @ozw1z5rd,My datanode's disks usage are all about 80%.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125273/discussion-between-ozw1z5rd-and-zmy).

Comment: Does this error comes during execution of a hadoop/spark job or it keeps on popping even when your cluster is free?

Comment: See this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-7175